# docker-php-ext-install gets stuck on Raspberry Pi (arm32v6)

Tags: php, docker, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to build a php image with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

It works fine on pc (amd64), but on a Raspberry Pi B+ (armv6) it gets stuck as soon as it reach the command, I can still type in the terminal, so it's not frozen, it just doesn't proceed.
I've also tried `php:8.0-fpm` and `arm32v6/php:7.4-fpm-alpine` to no avail.

Any clues?

Comment: try to use specific to arm architecture  https://hub.docker.com/r/armhf/php

Comment: @AbhishekDK I saw that page but it says `The armhf organization is deprecated in favor of the more-specific arm32v7 and arm32v6 organizations`, indeed as mentioned in the question I already tried the more specific `arm32v6/php:7.4-fpm-alpine`. Also all the tags at [armhf](https://hub.docker.com/r/armhf/php/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated) are `linux/arm64` so I can't even use them.

Comment: can you use the following image "balenalib/raspberry-pi"  , first run the image and check if php is already installed if not create a proper dockerfile installing php

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/balenalib/raspberry-pi

Comment: @AbhishekDK How do I install the `docker-php-ext-install` script inside it since it's not present by default like in the php image?

Comment: try to use this in Dockerfile RUN apt-get install -y php php-fpm pdo-mysql php-mbstring and then try

Comment: @AbhishekDK that would not answer the original question though. However I think I figured it out, I'll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be the package manager not working for users of x86, armv7, and armhf due to some outdated packages as stated [here](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1196) (Alpine >= 3.13) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libseccomp/+bug/1890332) (Debian >= bullseye).
The `docker-php-ext-install` script tries to use the package manager, which fails, but errors are not displayed making the issue unclear at first.

To solve this you can either run an image of php that uses Alpine < 3.13 / Debian < bullseye e.g. `php:7.0-fpm-alpine` (Alpine 3.7) / `php:8.0-fpm-buster` (Debian Buster), or use one of the fix in the links above (run the container with `--privileged` or manually update libseccomp).